# CSS: IE7 Blank area of <div> takes space

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have a page with some divs that have a width of 800px and margin: 0 auto
to center them.

One of the divs contains an image and the rest of the div is empty, in IE8+ it looks
as well as all other browsers, but in IE7 the empty area of the div takes space and throws other elements off their place,

is there a quick solution for making the empty area of the div not take space?

the reason I have to keep the blank area is that the fixed with and margin: 0 auto make
the picture align with the other divs that have the same width.

thx in advance!

Comment: Could you repro on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QPVKM/ that's the code but it only has the problem on IE7, there's an image inside the div.main and the rest of div.main is empty but still takes space. (in IE7 the img tag will be at a seperate line from the div.mainright)

Comment: my site is not live yet, in the end what I did as make an IE conditional comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wanted to tell anyone reading this post, what I did in the end is put an Internet Explorer conditional comment as nothing seemed to solve the problem.

another thing that is possible is to make one of the DIVs' position absolute and then it's
outside the normal flow, but I couldn't find a way to make the empty part of the DIV not take
space in the normal flow.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `line-height:0` and `font-size:0` for that element.

It should make the element occupy no space..

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does...just put `;` after them

I just had the same problem on IE7 and used the answer

```
line-height:0; 
font-size:0;
```

in the CSS corresponding to that div